# Java Thread.sleep waking up "much" earlier than the scheduled time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a requirement of writing a daemon which initiates number of threads that wakes up at different times. The daemon is written in Java using commons apache library and is run on a Linux machine (Fedora 13 ).
One thread wakes up everyday to perform task A which happens as scheduled.
But there is another thread which is scheduled to wake up every Monday at 6 am to perform some task which does not happen as scheduled. The problem is that this thread wakes up much before the actual scheduled time. It runs 2 days after the completion of the previous run though it should run only after a week. The waiting time is calculated correctly using our own timer class and because this reuses existing code i do not see a problem in this.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the problematic code as well as the timer class?

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is not the correct way to do job scheduling.  If you're sleeping any longer than a few seconds, you are almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden - Thanks for the reply. I was thinking if Java Timer is a good alternative to Thread.sleep

Comment: Quartz sounds like the best tool to use here. Its like cron for Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thread.sleep() doesn't make any guarantees, and it might wake up earlier than expected.  you should always use it in the loop:

```
long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while (wakeUpTime - curTime > 0) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(wakeUpTime - curTime);
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
  curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: ...or use one of the standard higher-level abstractions as appropriate... :-)

Comment: @iluxa- Thanks for the solution. Let me try it and see if it works.

Comment: There's no way this can't work, since in worst case (sleep returns instantly) you just implement busy waiting.