# Proper way to execute thread logic at a fixed rate

Tags: java

What is the proper way to invoke a thread's run() method at a fixed rate?

Should I implements [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and use [Thread#sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) in parallel with math based on [System#nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) or should I extends [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and use an [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)?

I would want this logic to be executed every #ms regardless of processing time, example:

```
Loop takes 32ms
Thread waits 228ms (250-32) then executes loop again.
Loop takes 17ms
Thread waits 233ms (250-17) then executes loop again.
```

This would mean that just using `Thread#sleep()` by itself would not be a proper solution, I know I can get pretty close to this effect by calculating the amount of milliseconds to sleep() using a start/end/elapsed variable and using nanoTime() for reference, but is this the "Correct" way to do it?

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService` is the right way.

Comment: It's hard to advise what the "best way" is for your use-case without more information about what you're trying to achieve, but an abstraction like `ScheduledExecutorService` is superior to sleeping a thread.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5045469/1394393